# unable to ssh to remote host via ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have two playbooks
Playbook1.yaml which installs dependencies as root user and is working as expected but playbook2 is giving errors. Can some one help look at it on why playbook2 is failing to run when majority of the code is same for both playbook 1 and 2?

**Playbook1 yaml file**

```
---
- name: Install Cognos Analytics
  hosts: all
  become_method: dzdo
  become_user: root
  become_flags: 'su -'

  tasks:
    - name: Install Cognos Analytics Dependencies
      yum:
        name:
          - java-1.8.0-openjdk
          - glibc.i686
          - glibc.x86_64
          - libstdc++.i686
          - libstdc++.x86_64
          - nspr.i686
          - nspr.x86_64
          - nss.i686
          - nss.x86_64
```

**Now Playbook2 yaml below is giving the following error when I try to run can someone help me on this ?**

```
---
- name: Install Cognos Analytics
  hosts: all
  become_method: dzdo
  become_user: root
  become_flags: 'su -'

 

  tasks:
    - name: Installing Cognos Analytics
      command: /apps/Softwares/ca_instl_lnxi38664_2.0.2003191.bin -f /apps/Softwares/cognosresponsefile.properties -i silent
      args:
        chdir: /apps/SilentInstall
```

**Error Log:**

```
TASK [Installing Cognos Analytics] **************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/Cognos.yml:9
<10.x.x.x> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: jughead
<10.x.x.x> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="jughead"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a67e55b20e 10.x.x.x '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~jughead && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.x.x.x> (0, '/home/jughead\n', '')
<10.x.x.x> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: jughead
<10.x.x.x> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="jughead"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a67e55b20e 10.x.x.x '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/jughead/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/jughead/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020="` echo /home/jughead/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.x.x.x> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020=/home/jughead/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020\n', '')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
<10.x.x.x> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-12346tPaVOe/tmpXlWUhD TO /home/jughead/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020/AnsiballZ_command.py
<10.x.x.x> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="jughead"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a67e55b20e '[10.x.x.x]'
<10.x.x.x> (0, 'sftp> put /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-12346tPaVOe/tmpXlWUhD /home/jughead/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', '')
<10.x.x.x> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: jughead
<10.x.x.x> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="jughead"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a67e55b20e 10.x.x.x '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/jughead/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020/ /home/jughead/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.x.x.x> (0, '', '')
<10.x.x.x> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: jughead
<10.x.x.x> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="jughead"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a67e55b20e -tt 10.x.x.x '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python /home/jughead/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.x.x.x> (1, '\r\n{"changed": true, "end": "2021-06-28 15:43:16.115767", "stdout": "", "cmd": ["/apps/Softwares/ca_instl_lnxi38664_2.0.2003191.bin", "-f", "/apps/Softwares/cognosresponsefile.properties", "-i", "silent"], "failed": true, "delta": "0:00:18.049758", "stderr": "", "rc": 255, "invocation": {"module_args": {"creates": null, "executable": null, "_uses_shell": false, "strip_empty_ends": true, "_raw_params": "/apps/Softwares/ca_instl_lnxi38664_2.0.2003191.bin -f /apps/Softwares/cognosresponsefile.properties -i silent", "removes": null, "argv": null, "warn": true, "chdir": "/apps/SilentInstall", "stdin_add_newline": true, "stdin": null}}, "start": "2021-06-28 15:42:58.066009", "msg": "non-zero return code"}\r\n', 'Shared connection to 10.x.x.x closed.\r\n')
<10.x.x.x> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 10.x.x.x closed.
<10.x.x.x> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: jughead
<10.x.x.x> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="jughead"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a67e55b20e 10.x.x.x '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/jughead/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624909377.53-12390-42703578539020/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.x.x.x> (0, '', '')
fatal: [10.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": [
        "/apps/Softwares/ca_instl_lnxi38664_2.0.2003191.bin", 
        "-f", 
        "/apps/Softwares/cognosresponsefile.properties", 
        "-i", 
        "silent"
    ], 
    "delta": "0:00:18.049758", 
    "end": "2021-06-28 15:43:16.115767", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "/apps/Softwares/ca_instl_lnxi38664_2.0.2003191.bin -f /apps/Softwares/cognosresponsefile.properties -i silent", 
            "_uses_shell": false, 
            "argv": null, 
            "chdir": "/apps/SilentInstall", 
            "creates": null, 
            "executable": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "stdin": null, 
            "stdin_add_newline": true, 
            "strip_empty_ends": true, 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "non-zero return code", 
    "rc": 255, 
    "start": "2021-06-28 15:42:58.066009", 
    "stderr": "", 
    "stderr_lines": [], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Comment: ` /apps/Softwares/ca_instl_lnxi38664_2.0.2003191.bin -f /apps/Softwares/cognosresponsefile.properties -i silent` is returning non zero return code. Meaning it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the only thing that makes sense is that Playbook 1 somehow affects Playbook 2, I searched for your issue and found this: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/475513
And this:
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2543805_1.html

Unfortunately none of these offer any solution, but just hints. Assuming that the installation of NSS is the issue, you could try to find out why the sshd might be failing from its logs.